# Update surrealDB data error,output info:Failed to resolve lock

Tags: locking, surrealdb

I run SurrealDB server with Docker,start command:"docker run --rm  -p 8000:8000 docker.io/surrealdb/surrealdb:latest start --log trace --user root --pass root tikv://10.206.0.9:2379",specifying the TiKV cluster endpoint as the backing data store.

1.I run "UPDATE account SET username.first = "Tobie",username.last = "Morgan Hitchcock"  where id="account:02vpvzway97jn2wj23kq" ",update one record is OK,return:

```
[
    {
        "time": "222.085746ms",
        "status": "OK",
        "result": [
            {
                "age": 18,
                "datatime": "2022-10-05T03:20:57.781059411Z",
                "id": "account:02vpvzway97jn2wj23kq",
                "name": "SurrealDB99",
                "password": "b50339a10e1de285ac99d4c3990b8693",
                "username": {
                    "first": "Tobie",
                    "last": "Morgan Hitchcock"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But update more record return ERR.
E.g UPDATE account SET password=crypto::md5(id) RETURN NONE; return:

```
[
    {
        "time": "1.035028887s",
        "status": "ERR",
        "detail": "There was a problem with a datastore transaction: Failed to resolve lock"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue with your query is that id is not defined , you can define in it a variable :

```
$id = "generate_id_using_surrealdb_funcs";
```

then you can use this $id to create a password .